# Finding first zero on either side of peaks

Tags: r, time-series

I have provided a visual example of my data. Additionally, I have provided an reproducible example of my data below. Please note that the reproducible example is provided at 1Hz, whereas the full data set is measured at 500Hz so some noise may be excluded but I believe this will still work as a good example.

```r
structure(list(Time = c(0.002, 1.002, 2.002, 3.002, 4.002,5.002,6.002,
 7.002, 8.002, 9.002, 10.002, 11.002, 12.002, 13.002, 14.002, 15.002, 
16.002, 17.002, 18.002, 19.002, 20.002, 21.002, 22.002, 23.002, 
24.002, 25.002, 26.002, 27.002, 28.002, 29.002), 
Force = c(-0.162079511, -1.206931702, 0.858307849, 0.130479103, 
-0.108053007, -0.100917431, -0.058103976, -0.054026504, 57.03465851,
 58.60142712, 56.7930683, 6.370030581, 25.48012232, 51.46687054, 
50.4108053, 11.50254842, -0.276248726, -0.076452599, -0.305810398, 
56.2803262, 57.32721713, 54.72579001, 53.58715596, 52.39143731, 
50.87461774, 50.91946993, -2.334352701, 1.342507645, 0.288481142, 23.92762487)), 
row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
```

The below data is a measurement of force that fluctuates with periods of high force (7 seconds of duration) and periods of no force (3 seconds of duration).

Note: Periods of 'no-force' are defined as scenarios where the force is < 1.0 (Kg).

I would like to 1) find the average force output during the plateau phase of each high force period. and 2) during the no force periods, in reality, there is some noise and force does not read zero. Therefore, I would like to find the first 'zero' point on either side of a peak and change all the 'no force periods' to zero so that I can accurately calculate the integral of the whole data set.

Could someone please provide some insight into what I should do to achieve these goals in R?

[image: Force vs Time]

Comment: I think you need to define what determines the "no force periods"; without that, this is impossible.  And that's not a programming question, it depends on your subject matter.

Comment: Agree with userNNNNN. Also you need to provide data in a form that can be pasted into a console session.

Comment: i.e. `dput(head(my_forceful_data) n = 20)`, then copy `structure(...)` above between three backticks ```, above and below, as your data.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insight everyone. I have provided a reproducible data set from the dput() function. Additionally, I have provided some more detailed data definitions. In summary: periods of 'no force' are defined as when force is < 1. and periods of 'high force' are all other scenarios. Although my desire to calculate the plateau at each 'high force' should not include the whole force period but only the plateau (approximately the middle 5 out of 7 seconds of the high force period). 

Thank you for your very valuable insight

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start, using `rle()` (run-length encoding) to compute the beginnings and ends of runs of low force.  (I used a threshold of 1.5 since that looked more appropriate for your data.)

```r
r <- rle(dd$Force<1.5)
ind <- c(0,cumsum(r$lengths))
f <- dd$Force
for (i in 1:(length(ind)-1)) {
    if (i %% 2 == 1) {   ## odd values are zero-force periods
                         ## (may need to be careful/generalize this for your data)
        ## cat(ind[i], ind[i+1]-1, "\n")
        f[(ind[i]+1):(ind[i+1]-1)] <- 0
    }
}
```

```r
plot(Force ~ Time, data = dd, type = "b")
abline(h=1.5, lty = 2)
abline(v=ind, col=4)
lines(dd$Time, f, col = 2)
```

[image]

You can use the indices computed above to extract 'force periods' and (defining 'plateau' however you want) compute averages etc. ...